# What Ubuntu/Debian packages do I need to build with Java+OpenGL?

Tags: java, opengl, ubuntu, clojure, jogl

I want to use JOGL (for Clojure, not Java). There seems to be quite a combination of alternatives for JDKs and OpenGL bindings, and I don't want to use a scatter gun approach and clog up my machine installing too much cruft. Please help me get started!

- What Ubuntu/Debian packages do I need to install? (starting with `sun-java6-jdk`, for example)
- There don't seem to be JOGL packages, so what's the best way to install it? Should I build from CVS HEAD, or use pre-built jar files?

I'll be using Emacs as my IDE so I don't need to install Eclipse or anything, I just need to be able to build with ant or whatever.

Please feel free to revise your answer (building on others' answers) to provide a comprehensive how-to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with Ubuntu 8.10 (intrepid), JOGL is already packaged ([**libjogl-java**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/intrepid/libjogl-java)). The best JDK to chose should be **openjdk-6-jdk** as it is in main(=supported by Ubuntu's core team) since intrepid and derived from Sun's proprietary JDK6 anyway.

On intrepid, just running

```
sudo apt-get install -y ant openjdk-6-jdk libjogl-java
```

should get you started. On older versions, you must leave out libjogl-java, manually install all the [dependencies](http://packages.ubuntu.com/intrepid/libjogl-java) (everything with a red circle) and build JOGL (download, unpack, ant).

Comment: I didn't realise JOGL was in 8.10. (I've been putting off upgrading because my system is stable). Thanks for your advice on manually installing.